# How to automatically set the header when it's not the first line of the file?

Tags: csv, symfony4

The csv files I work on all have a different number of lines before the header. I need to set the header automatically according to the file.

Here is an example of file:

```
            Wine Directory List



            Wine Title  Vintage Country Region  Sub region  Appellation Color   Bottle Size Price   URL FORMAT
Chateau Petrus Pomerol  2011    France  Bordeaux    Pomerol     Red 750ML   2799.99 HTTP://holbrookliquors.com/sku218758.html   1x750ML
Pappy Van Winkle's Bourbon 15 Year Family Reserve       United States   Kentucky                0ML 999.99      1x0ML
Shipping Fee                            0ML 999.99  1x0ML
Heineken Holland Beer       Netherlands                 0ML 999.99  1x0ML
```

Here is my converter :

UPDATE : first piece of solution : getHeaderLine(). Only setback : As I started parsing the file using getHeaderLine(), I can't get the data from HeaderLine, as I've already read the line in getHeaderLine. 
Please, someone out there help me.

```
public function convert($filePath, $feedColumnsMatch)
{

    //this array will contain the elements from the file
    $articles = [];

    $headerRecord = [];

        //if we can open the file on mode "read"
        if (($handle = fopen($filePath, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
            //represents the line we are reading
            $rowCounter = 0;
            $nb = $feedColumnsMatch->getNumberOfColumns();

            $headerLine = $this->getHeaderLine($handle, $nb, $delimiter);

            //as long as there are lines
            while (($rowData = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
//todo enlever le vilain 9
                if ($nb===count($rowData)) {

                    //At x line, are written the keys so we record them in $headerRecord
 //What I had first     if (9 === $rowCounter) {
//What I now have
                        if(0 === $rowCounter) {
                        //trim the titles of columns
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $nb; $i++) {
                            $rowData[$i] = trim($rowData[$i]);
                        }

                        $headerRecord = $rowData;
                    }
                    elseif(9<$rowCounter )
                    {      //for every other lines...
                        foreach ($rowData as $key => $value) {       //in each line, for each value
                            // we set $value to the cell ($key) having the same horizontal position than $value
                            // but where vertical position = 0 (headerRecord[]
                            $articles[$rowCounter][$headerRecord[$key]] = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8");

                        }
                    }
                }
                $rowCounter++;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

    return $articles;
}

 public function getHeaderLine($handle, $nbColumns, $delimiter){
        $rowCounter = 0;
        while (($rowData = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            $rowCounter++;
            if ($nbColumns===count($rowData)){
                return $rowCounter;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }
```

As you can see I have to write "9" in the if() to be able to parse the data correctly and to change it for each file.

Comment: I created a new function in my class converter just to get the headerLine. For that, I parse the file until I find the right number of cells (count($rowData). Then I return the rowCounter.

Comment: Looks like it's a tsv file instead of csv file since the values are separated by tab

Comment: @Andreas well yes. I make my function so that it accepts all delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have  csv/tsv files that start with a different number of non valid lines (blank or titles or tags or whatever), the solution to get the header is to parse the file a first time thanks to a side function. The first line that has the right number of cells (you're supposed to know how many columns your csv file has) is your header.That way you can return the data of the header to the main function and keep on parsing from where you stopped reading in the side function.

The whole code:

```
public function convert($filePath, $feedColumnsMatch)
    {

        if(!file_exists($filePath) ) {
            return "existe pas";
        }
        if(!is_readable($filePath)) {
            return "pas lisible";
        }

        //this array will contain the elements from the file
        $articles = [];

        if($feedColumnsMatch->getFeedFormat()==="tsv" | $feedColumnsMatch->getFeedFormat()==="csv"){
            if($feedColumnsMatch->getFeedFormat()==="csv"){
                $delimiter = $feedColumnsMatch->getDelimiter();
            }else{
                $delimiter = "\t";
            }

            //if we can open the file on mode "read"
            if (($handle = fopen($filePath, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
                //represents the line we are reading

                $nb = $feedColumnsMatch->getNumberOfColumns();
                $headerRecord = $this->getHeader($handle, $nb, $delimiter);           // With this function, I start parsing the file till line === $headerLine
                $rowCounter = 0;
                //if there is no header
                if (null!==$headerRecord || false!==$headerRecord) {
                    //as long as there are lines
                    while (($rowData = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {

                        //if it is a line with valid number of cells
                        if ($nb === count($rowData)) {

                            foreach ($rowData as $key => $value) {       //in each line, for each value
                                // we set $value to the cell ($key) having the same horizontal position than $value
                                // but where vertical position = 0 (headerRecord[]
                                $articles[$rowCounter][$headerRecord[$key]] = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8");
                            }
                        }
                        $rowCounter++;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    new \Exception();
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
        return $articles;
    }


    /**
     * is used to get the data of the row containing the header of the csv file or null if no header
     * @param $handle
     * @param $nbColumns
     * @param $delimiter
     * @return array|false|null
     */
    public function getHeader($handle, $nbColumns, $delimiter){
        $rowCounter = 0;
        while (($rowData = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            $rowCounter++;
            if ($nbColumns===count($rowData)){
                //trim the titles of columns
                for ($i = 0; $i < $nbColumns; $i++) {
                    $rowData[$i] = trim($rowData[$i]);
                }

                return $rowData;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, I don't know if it's the right way to do it. It's just a way that works.